# Trouble using forEach and mongoose's findById in tandem

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am writing a Node route which should push objects onto an array declared outside the forEach loop after the objects have a property added to them. When I console.log the array within the loop, it seems to be taking on data, but when I return it to the client-side. It is empty.

```
            var todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency = [];

            listOfItemIdsAndSaleFrequency.forEach((item) => {

                Product.findById(item.itemId).then((foundItem) => {

                    var fullItemData = foundItem.toJSON();

                    fullItemData.occurrences = item.occurrences;

                    todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency.push(fullItemData);

                    console.log(todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency);

                });

            });

            return res.status(200).json(todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency);
```

The console.log statement shows that the array called todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency is being populated correctly, but why is it empty when I return it to the client?

Answer (score 1):

The callback function you're passing to `Product.findById(item.itemId).then(...)` is not invoked immediately.  Your outer `forEach` completes and you `return` before any of your callbacks are invoked.

Mongoose's `findById()` method [returns a *promise*](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).  You can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for an array of promises to complete, and then set `res.status(200).json(...)`.  Because this happens asynchronously you should also present an asynchronous interface, for example by returning a promise yourself.

Here's a version that gathers all of the responses and returns a promise that resolves with your original return value:

```
var todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency = [];

return Promise.all(listOfItemIdsAndSaleFrequency.map((item) => {

    return Product.findById(item.itemId).then((foundItem) => {

        var fullItemData = foundItem.toJSON();

        fullItemData.occurrences = item.occurrences;

        todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency.push(fullItemData);

        console.log(todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency);

    });

})).then(() => res.status(200).json(todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency));
```

Comment: I made these adjustments and what you're saying makes sense to me, but it appears that the last "then" statement that should send a status 200 and todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency never executes. It never finishes.

Comment: Hmm... the promise may be getting rejected for some reason.  You could try putting a [`.catch(err => console.log("failed", err))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) after the final `.then()` to see.